# How to modify glibc in Ubuntu to alter the results of printf() function

Tags: c, ubuntu, printf, glibc

I want to modify glibc in Ubunto to let the result of printf() include some other components instead of just print what are in printf(). For example, if i enter printf("Hello World"), I want the result to be 'J.Doe, Hello World' that the result includes my name in front of what's in printf(). How can I do this by modifying some files in glibc?

Comment: That is an incredibly bad idea.  If you really want to overload `printf`, just write your own version and link with it.  Don't try to maintain your own libraries.

Comment: [Don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do this? What is the actual problem you want to solve by it? I suggest you take some time to read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because your question is a perfect example of it.

Comment: This is some kind of projects from where I learn Ubuntu, but I do not have any idea about the problem...

Comment: Actually this is *not* really possible, because redefining a built-in function has undefined behaviour. Use GCC, and `printf("hello world\n");` doesn't even **call the `printf` function**!

Comment: Perhaps use a macro instead.

Comment: Like #define myprintf(fmt,...)  printf("Myname:");printf (fmt, __VA_ARGS__)

Comment: His question seems fairly clear to me. He wants to modify the system's printf() function so that every call to it will do something new that he added to the function (like print his name along with the string). He wants to have fun!

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the glibc package.  The version I've been working with is glibc-2.23.tar.gz.
2. Make sure you can build it.  (This isn't so easy -- it's a huge, complicated package, with lots of system dependencies.)
3. Make sure you can link a C program against your newly-built libc, not the one in /usr/lib.
4. Now you're ready to start modifying printf.  The common code for all the printf variants is in stdio-common/vfprintf.c.  Beware! It's complicated, sophisticated code; this is not the most straightforward, easy-to-understand implementation to learn from.

If you want a more straightforward, easy-to-understand implementation of printf to play with and learn from, there's one in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html).